# Converting from mysql to mysqli, getting empty results with this query

Tags: php, mysqli

This query never returns results, even when there is a match and it should be giving me something. var_dump($result) always returns NULL. $con is valid and the code gives no errors.

```
$con = new mysqli($dbHostname,$dbUsername,$dbPwd,$dbName);
$dbQuery = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM People WHERE UCASE(EmailAddress) = UCASE(?) AND (Status = 'A' OR Status = 'M')";
$stmt = $con->prepare($dbQuery);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
```

I'm new to mysqli so I've probably just done something dumb here. Please tell me what I missed.

Comment: try this instead of $dbQuery. 
`"SELECT `Field1`,`Field2` FROM `People` WHERE UCASE(`EmailAddress`) = UCASE(?) AND (`Status`='A' OR `Status`='M')"` I had a similar issue yesterday, where the query failed with error when the '`' were missing.

Answer (score -1):

I commented, but the formatting was messed up, here is what I am suggesting. Instead of the dbQuery string you currently have, try this:

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT `Field1`,`Field2` FROM `People` WHERE UCASE(`EmailAddress`) = UCASE(?) AND (`Status`='A' OR `Status`='M')";
```

A similar problem outputted errors for me, when not including ` in SQL string.

Comment: It's still empty. I added a var_dump on $stmt which confirms it has no rows. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Tried it using PDO instead of mysqli and had no problems so I guess I'm just going to learn PDO. Consider this solved.

Comment: @AnonymousMan consider marking it solved and accepting the answer if it helped you solve the question, so that it would be easier for others to find solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: Not seeing any way to mark it solved. I can't accept this answer as it didn't really help (see my comments) so not really sure what you expect me to do here.

Answer (score -2):

I don't like working with bind_params, but I don't see the $email variable being set to a value. I'd like to assume you did, but obviously if that variable is empty you'll never get a result.

Also, if you have access you can turn on debugging on the mysql server and see what it has to say about this request.